# get single value from sql-query into a textbox

Tags: vb.net, dataset, streamreader

The result of my sql-query is a single value i want display that in a lable but dont know how. I have a solution creating a dataset put the result of the query into that dataset and get it by row(0),column(0) but i guess there is a smarter way doing it.

```
Private myquery As String

Sub New(ByVal query As String)
    myquery = query
End Sub
Public Sub query_Send()
    Dim myconn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DB;Integrated Security=TRUE")
    Dim mycmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Me.myQuery, myconn)
    Dim myTable As New DataTable
    Dim previousConnectionState As ConnectionState = myconn.State
    Try
        If myconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            myconn.Open()
            Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter(mycmd)
            myDA.Fill(myTable)
            tb.text = **...**
        End If
        If previousConnectionState = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            myconn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

```
Dim querystr as String = "select value from MyTable where ID=5"
Dim mycmd As New SqlCommand(querystr, connection)
dim value as Object = mycmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

The `value` you can put to your textbox. ExecuteScalar returns first value of first row of the resultset (equivalent of `row(0).column(0)` )  When no record is returned the `value` is `nothing`.

Comment: works for me, thanks
CODE

Dim sql As String
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
con.Open()
sql = "SELECT MAX(pos) FROM rac"
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = sql
Dim value As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar
Me.TextBox6.Text = value + 1

Answer (score 0):

Try something more along the lines of:

```
    Using myconn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DB;Integrated Security=TRUE")
        Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter()
        myDA.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(myQuery, myconn)
        myDA.Fill(myTable)
        Return myTable 
    End Using
```

Or you can just get ahold of the first item in the first row with

`myTable.Rows(0).ItemArray(0).ToString()`